# Database loading Product Collection slow (Minutes)

Tags: collection, sql, performance, mariadb

I've got some third party code here that loads a larger product collection. It takes around 9 minutes to load on decent hardware. We have some 150000 SKU in the database.

Collection:

SQL is:

```
SELECT DISTINCT  `e`.*,
                IF(at_status.value_id > 0, at_status.value, at_status_default.value) AS `status`,
                IF(at_visibility.value_id > 0, at_visibility.value, at_visibility_default.value) AS `visibility`,
                `price_index`.`price`,
                `price_index`.`tax_class_id`,
                `price_index`.`final_price`,
                IF(price_index.tier_price IS NOT NULL, LEAST(price_index.min_price, price_index.tier_price), price_index.min_price) AS `minimal_price`,
                `price_index`.`min_price`,
                `price_index`.`max_price`,
                `price_index`.`tier_price`,
                (SELECT MAX(rating_summary) FROM review_entity_summary AS o
                    WHERE o.entity_pk_value = e.entity_id AND o.store_id = 2) AS `rating_summary`
        FROM `catalog_product_entity` AS `e`
       INNER JOIN `catalog_product_website` AS `product_website` ON product_website.product_id = e.entity_id AND product_website.website_id = 2
       INNER JOIN `catalog_product_entity_int` AS `at_status_default` ON (`at_status_default`.`entity_id` = `e`.`entity_id`) AND (`at_status_default`.`attribute_id` = '97') AND `at_status_default`.`store_id` = 0
       LEFT JOIN `catalog_product_entity_int` AS `at_status` ON (`at_status`.`entity_id` = `e`.`entity_id`) AND (`at_status`.`attribute_id` = '97') AND (`at_status`.`store_id` = 2)
       INNER JOIN `catalog_product_entity_int` AS `at_visibility_default` ON (`at_visibility_default`.`entity_id` = `e`.`entity_id`) AND (`at_visibility_default`.`attribute_id` = '99') AND `at_visibility_default`.`store_id` = 0
       LEFT JOIN `catalog_product_entity_int` AS `at_visibility` ON (`at_visibility`.`entity_id` = `e`.`entity_id`) AND (`at_visibility`.`attribute_id` = '99') AND (`at_visibility`.`store_id` = 2)
       INNER JOIN `catalog_product_index_price` AS `price_index` ON price_index.entity_id = e.entity_id AND price_index.customer_group_id = 0 AND price_index.website_id = '2'
        WHERE (((IF(at_status.value_id > 0, at_status.value, at_status_default.value) = '1')))
          AND (IF(at_visibility.value_id > 0, at_visibility.value, at_visibility_default.value) IN(3, 2, 4))
```

mariadb tells me on an analyze:

| id | select_type | table | type | possible_keys | key | key_len | ref | rows | r_rows | filtered | r_filtered | Extra |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | PRIMARY | product_website | ref | "PRIMARY,CATALOG_PRODUCT_WEBSITE_WEBSITE_ID" | CATALOG_PRODUCT_WEBSITE_WEBSITE_ID | 2 | const | 82150 | 50902.00 | 100 | 100 | Using index; Using temporary |
| 1 | PRIMARY | e | eq_ref | PRIMARY | PRIMARY | 4 | magento2.product_website.product_id | 1 | 1.00 | 100 | 100 | "" |
| 1 | PRIMARY | at_status | eq_ref | "CATALOG_PRODUCT_ENTITY_INT_ENTITY_ID_ATTRIBUTE_ID_STORE_ID,CATALOG_PRODUCT_ENTITY_INT_ATTRIBUTE_ID,CATALOG_PRODUCT_ENTITY_INT_STORE_ID,CATALOG_PRODUCT_ENTITY_INT_ATTRIBUTE_ID_STORE_ID_VALUE,CATALOG_PRODUCT_ENTITY_INT_ENTITY_ID" | CATALOG_PRODUCT_ENTITY_INT_ENTITY_ID_ATTRIBUTE_ID_STORE_ID | 8 | "magento2.product_website.product_id,const,const" | 1 | 0.00 | 0 | 100 | "" |
| 1 | PRIMARY | at_visibility | ref | "CATALOG_PRODUCT_ENTITY_INT_ENTITY_ID_ATTRIBUTE_ID_STORE_ID,CATALOG_PRODUCT_ENTITY_INT_ATTRIBUTE_ID,CATALOG_PRODUCT_ENTITY_INT_STORE_ID,CATALOG_PRODUCT_ENTITY_INT_ATTRIBUTE_ID_STORE_ID_VALUE,CATALOG_PRODUCT_ENTITY_INT_ENTITY_ID" | CATALOG_PRODUCT_ENTITY_INT_STORE_ID | 2 | const | 1 |  | 0.00 | 100 | 100 |
| 1 | PRIMARY | at_status_default | ref | "CATALOG_PRODUCT_ENTITY_INT_ENTITY_ID_ATTRIBUTE_ID_STORE_ID,CATALOG_PRODUCT_ENTITY_INT_ATTRIBUTE_ID,CATALOG_PRODUCT_ENTITY_INT_STORE_ID,CATALOG_PRODUCT_ENTITY_INT_ATTRIBUTE_ID_STORE_ID_VALUE,CATALOG_PRODUCT_ENTITY_INT_ENTITY_ID" | CATALOG_PRODUCT_ENTITY_INT_ENTITY_ID | 4 | magento2.product_website.product_id | 9 | 9.11 | 11.14 | 8.83 | Using where |
| 1 | PRIMARY | at_visibility_default | ref | "CATALOG_PRODUCT_ENTITY_INT_ENTITY_ID_ATTRIBUTE_ID_STORE_ID,CATALOG_PRODUCT_ENTITY_INT_ATTRIBUTE_ID,CATALOG_PRODUCT_ENTITY_INT_STORE_ID,CATALOG_PRODUCT_ENTITY_INT_ATTRIBUTE_ID_STORE_ID_VALUE,CATALOG_PRODUCT_ENTITY_INT_ENTITY_ID" | CATALOG_PRODUCT_ENTITY_INT_ENTITY_ID | 4 | magento2.product_website.product_id | 9 | 9.24 | 11.18 | 10.82 | Using where |
| 1 | PRIMARY | price_index | ref | "PRIMARY,CATALOG_PRODUCT_INDEX_PRICE_CUSTOMER_GROUP_ID,CAT_PRD_IDX_PRICE_WS_ID_CSTR_GROUP_ID_MIN_PRICE" | CAT_PRD_IDX_PRICE_WS_ID_CSTR_GROUP_ID_MIN_PRICE | 6 | "const,const" | 91136 | 1.00 | 100 | 100 | Using index condition |
| 2 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | o | ref | "REVIEW_ENTITY_SUMMARY_ENTITY_PK_VALUE_STORE_ID_ENTITY_TYPE,REVIEW_ENTITY_SUMMARY_STORE_ID" | REVIEW_ENTITY_SUMMARY_ENTITY_PK_VALUE_STORE_ID_ENTITY_TYPE | 10 | "magento2.e.entity_id,const" | 1 | 0.00 | 100 | 100 | Using index condition |

Comment: Just to be clear, what is your *question*?

Comment: I want to understand why that is so slow, and what do do about that. Grabbing that data set from the database should not take minutes. I can do a full DB import faster than that-

Answer (score 0):

I think this Select could be slow because, your sub-select in your select can not be optimized automaticaly and will run over 150000 times.
This sub-select is not heavy but runs 150000 with out a re-use.

If you put in the sub-select in the from part, it will run just once. This could look like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT  `e`.*,
             IF(at_status.value_id > 0, at_status.value, at_status_default.value) AS `status`,
             IF(at_visibility.value_id > 0, at_visibility.value, at_visibility_default.value) AS `visibility`,
             `price_index`.`price`,
             `price_index`.`tax_class_id`,
             `price_index`.`final_price`,
             IF(price_index.tier_price IS NOT NULL, LEAST(price_index.min_price, price_index.tier_price), price_index.min_price) AS `minimal_price`,
             `price_index`.`min_price`,
             `price_index`.`max_price`,
             `price_index`.`tier_price`,
             rating_summary.mx as rating_summary
FROM `catalog_product_entity` AS `e`
LEFT JOIN
 (SELECT e.entity_id, MAX(rating_summary) as mx
  FROM review_entity_summary AS o,
       catalog_product_entity as e
  WHERE o.entity_pk_value = e.entity_id AND o.store_id = 2
  GROUP BY e.entity_id) AS `rating_summary` ON e.entity_id = rating_summary.entity_id
     INNER JOIN `catalog_product_website` AS `product_website` ON product_website.product_id = e.entity_id AND product_website.website_id = 2
     INNER JOIN `catalog_product_entity_int` AS `at_status_default` ON (`at_status_default`.`entity_id` = `e`.`entity_id`) AND (`at_status_default`.`attribute_id` = '97') AND `at_status_default`.`store_id` = 0
     LEFT JOIN `catalog_product_entity_int` AS `at_status` ON (`at_status`.`entity_id` = `e`.`entity_id`) AND (`at_status`.`attribute_id` = '97') AND (`at_status`.`store_id` = 2)
     INNER JOIN `catalog_product_entity_int` AS `at_visibility_default` ON (`at_visibility_default`.`entity_id` = `e`.`entity_id`) AND (`at_visibility_default`.`attribute_id` = '99') AND `at_visibility_default`.`store_id` = 0
     LEFT JOIN `catalog_product_entity_int` AS `at_visibility` ON (`at_visibility`.`entity_id` = `e`.`entity_id`) AND (`at_visibility`.`attribute_id` = '99') AND (`at_visibility`.`store_id` = 2)
     INNER JOIN `catalog_product_index_price` AS `price_index` ON price_index.entity_id = e.entity_id AND price_index.customer_group_id = 0 AND price_index.website_id = '2' 
WHERE (((IF(at_status.value_id > 0, at_status.value, at_status_default.value) = '1')))
AND (IF(at_visibility.value_id > 0, at_visibility.value, at_visibility_default.value) IN(3, 2, 4));
```